# Render a PDF byte[] in WPF component

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pdf

I’m working in WPF .Net framework project, and I need rendering byte[] of database on a component on screen.. I can do this ? I tried webBrowser component, image component but didn’t work.

Example of my attempt: *pdfParaExibir* is a WebBrowser native component

```
private void RenderizarPdfEntrega(FileStream pdf)
{
    //pdfParaExibir.NavigateToString(pdf.Name);

    pdfParaExibir.Navigate(new System.Uri("about:blank"));
    pdfParaExibir.Navigate(new System.Uri(@"C:\temp\teste\Luiz3.pdf"));
    //pdfParaExibir.NavigateToString(@"C:\temp\teste\Luiz3.pdf");
}
```

I tried webBrowser component, image component but didn’t work.

My expectations is show the pdf file on screen without possibility of save on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a URI, call the method that accepts a string:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="theBrowser" />
```

And then in code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.theBrowser.Navigate(@"c:\somefolder\yourfile.pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried this before but the same thing, now I noticed that the component is created but not displayed on the screen

Comment: @LuizErler are you displaying anything else on the screen? Any possibility your layouts have collapsed it?